# how can i create a circle with the text inside?

Tags: css, drupal, sass

I want to create a circle for my link. I work with Drupal and my twig is this:

```
<div class="field field--name-link field--type-link field--label-hidden field--item">
    <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer">See map</a>
</div>
```

and my SASS is empty for the moment, but the subtlety is: try to do not use height : 40px and width: 80px.

Something with max-width, padding, etc... I would like to make this circle but in another way. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the height and width rule, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


.wrapper-circle {
  border-radius: 500rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  min-width: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.4em 1.4em .6em 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="wrapper-circle">
    See map
  </a>
</div>
```

It only use `min-height` and `min-width` and some `padding`.

The `.container` class provide nothing, it's just to be displayed correctly in the snippet.

Note that if you change the text you will have to change the padding to fit perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. Djamel provides a suibtable solution and of course that will work just as well as my solution however this will not work if you want to make the element responsive.

My solution is the following:

```css
.circle {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
     border-radius:250px;
     font-size:50px;
     color:#fff;
     background:#000;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .inner-circle {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="inner-circle">
    Hello I am A Circle
  </div>
</div>
```

In practice, using translation is still the correct way for a responsive circle with content in it. You 'could' use flex but of course that comes with lack of support for some older browsers. But generally you might find its not an issue.

To make it fully responsive you would use max-width/height properties instead.

If you want to use flex instead use this solution:

```css
.circle
    {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    .inner-circle {
      /* No code needed */
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="inner-circle">
    Hello I am A Circle
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, this is a solution for you.